# Prolog: How to check if variable is initialized before use?

Tags: variables, prolog, initialization

I have a code that looks like this:

```
path(Node1, Node2, Distance):- edge(Node1, Node2, Dist),
    Distance is Dist + Distance, !.
```

This rule will be called recursively; however, whenever I try to call it an error occurs stating that Distance isn't sufficiently initialized. Why is this happening? I assume the solution would be to check if Distance is initialized in the first place. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code wouldn't anyway do what you want it to do. Is it supposed to calculate distance between nodes in graph? Than you start with this piece of code (not tested):

```
path(Node1, Node2, Dist):-edge(Node1, Node2, Dist), !.   (0)
path(Node1, Node2, Dist):-
      edge(Node1, NodeBetween, DistToBetween), 
      path(NodeBetween, Node2, DistFromBetween), (1)
      Dist is DistToBetween + DistFromBetween.   (2)
```

Now when you ask the Prolog engine like `path(a,b,Distance)` it will give you distance between a and b in variable Distance.

Little bit informal description of what happens here: 
The variable will be 'initialized' in `edge(Node1, Node2, Dist), !.` (0) and will be initialized to the distance between `Node1` and `Node2` and than other numbers will be added to it while Prolog will evaluate (1) and than (2).

However, logical programming is different than 'usual' procedural programming, one have to manage to think little bit differently. Good luck with that. Btw. SWI prolog has nice debugger, which can quiet help to understand what's happening under the hood when a predicate is being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use Distance in `Distance is Dist + Distance, !.` while it's not initialized.

You're trying to add Distance to Distance before initializing it.

Probably what you're trying to do is

```
path(Node1, Node2, Distance):- edge(Node1, Node2, Dist), Distance is Dist.
```

**Edit**

Try doing the same without mixing input and output variables:

```
path(Node1, Node2, Distance):- path(Node1, Node2, Distance).
path(Node1, Node2, InitialDistance, Distance):- edge(Node1, Node2, Dist), 
                                                Distance is InitialDistance + Dist, !.
```

Comment: Yes, so I believe the solution is to check if it's not initialized, then set it equal to 0, otherwise add up to it. How can this be done in prolog?

Comment: I'm not a Prolog expert, but I believe you can't mix input and output variables and can't either check if a variable is initialized. I'll edit my answer to a different approach.

Comment: I know this works; however, this is not what I want to do. IF I directly set Distance to be equal Dist then I'll lose the accumulated value of Distance.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either; however, thank you for your effort.